# High severity vulnerabilities after setting up a reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm starting a brand new project with react-js, after installing the project with npm, I get high severity vulnerabilities, how can I fix these vulnerabilities? would it cause any problems?
when I run the command `npm start` everything seems to work just fine.

I have tried running "npm audit fix" but it says: fixed 0 of 8646 vulnerabilities.

**When I run this command:**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
npx: installed 91 in 27.693s

Creating a new React app in E:\My project\ReactJS\Training\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall E:\My project\ReactJS\Training\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall E:\My project\ReactJS\Training\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

+ react-dom@16.8.6
+ react@16.8.6
+ react-scripts@3.0.1
added 1411 packages from 726 contributors and audited 902137 packages in 287.343s
found 8646 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created my-app at E:\My project\ReactJS\Training\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

**After that, I tried running this:**

```
npm audit fix
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.14.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.6 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 10.513s
fixed 0 of 8646 vulnerabilities in 902137 scanned packages
  8646 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing to worry about according to [gaearon](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7364#issuecomment-511040805)

"This is not a real “vulnerability” in the context of Create React App because it produces static bundles. So it can’t possibly affect you in any way.

The false positive warnings are unfortunate."

EDIT: For me currently is says there are now 0 vulnerabilities